# mysql select - select AVG() query doesn't return when columns does not exist

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, average

I'm trying to make a select with percetaje average. These are my tables:

**tb_module**

```
ID_MOD                   MODULE                   ID_PR
  1                     Module 1                    1
  2                     Module 2                    1
  3                     Module 3                    2
```

**tb_activity**

```
ID_ACT                 ID_MOD                    ACTIVITY
   1                      1                     Activity 1.1
   2                      1                     Activity 1.2
   3                      2                     Activity 2.1
   4                      2                     Activity 2.2
```

**tb_percentaje**

```
ID_PERC                ID_ACT                PERCENTAJE
   1                     1                       20
   2                     2                       10
   3                     3                       70
   4                     4                       50
```

One of my `QUERY`S is like this----> `WHERE ID_PRO = 1` ( when module has activity(ies) ) :

```
ID_MOD                      MODULE                      AVG(PERCENTAJE)
   1                       Module 1                          15
   2                       Module 2                          60
```

But, when module doesn't have activity(ies) ------> `WHERE ID_PRO = 2`. Query returns 0 rows.

How can i fix this issue?

Should be like this, `WHERE ID_PRO = 2`

```
ID_MOD                      MODULE                      AVG(PERCENTAJE)
  3                        Module 3                          0
```

'0' because doesn't have activity.

Comment: How do you intend to differentiate between a module with no activities and one with activities whose average percentage is 0?  In any event, you probably want to use an *outer* join.  See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.ID_MOD, m.MODULE, AVG(p.PERCENTAJE)
FROM tb_module m 
LEFT JOIN tb_activity a ON m.ID_MOD = a.ID_MOD 
LEFT JOIN tb_percentaje p ON a.ID_ACT = p.ID_ACT 
WHERE m.ID_PRO = 2
GROUP BY m.ID_MOD
```

Comment: Works fine with `WHER ID_PRO = 1` ... with `2` , return 0 rows

Comment: Making some changes, finally i got it ... Thank you so much!